# How get multi selected values from a `Selectlist`?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

How to get multi selected values from a `Selectlist`?

Here is what I tried so far: following code below gets only gets the one value so issue might be with line `Colors = Request.Query["Colors"];`

```
<form asp-page="./index" method="get">
     <select asp-for="Colors" asp-items="@Model.Colors_SELECT" class="MultiSelect" multiple>
        <option value="">All</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

url example:
https://localhost:7221/Index?Colors=&Blk&Colors=red&Colors=blue

back-end code

```
   [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string? Colors { get; set; }
    public SelectList? Colors_SELECT { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
           // Fill select values
           Colors_SELECT = new SelectList(_services.Fill_Colors(), "Value", "Text", 1);
      
        // selected values 
        Colors = Request.Query["Colors"];
    }
```

helper function to fill colors

```
    public List<SelectListItem> Fill_Colors()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> Query = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem() { Value = "Black", Text = "blk" },
            new SelectListItem() { Value = "red", Text = "red" },
            new SelectListItem() { Value = "blue", Text = "blue" }
        };

        return Query;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the type of the `Colors` property to string array:

`public string[]? Colors { get; set; }`

Then when `OnGetAsync` is called the `Colors` array will contain the values from the query string.

```cs
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public string[]? Colors { get; set; }
public SelectList? Colors_SELECT { get; set; }

public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    // Fill select values
    Colors_SELECT = new SelectList(_services.Fill_Colors(), "Value", "Text", 1);
  
    // selected values
    foreach(var color in Colors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(color);
    }
    // https://localhost:7221/Index?Colors=black&Colors=red&Colors=blue
    // will print: "black", "red", "blue"
}
```

Comment: do you know why its sending `Colors` name multi times in url. it should be simple to send just `Colors=black,red,blue` right?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#collections